# Set up HTTPS on AWS S3 without using a custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, https

After having enable the *Static Web Server* function in our S3 bucket I got something which looks like:

`http://our-bucket-name.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/`

However I want to be able to use this exact domain with https.
So far I have found out a whole heap of guides how to set up cloudfront with your own custom domain, but I want to simply be able to use the above domain over HTTP and HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

As noted at [Key Differences Between the Amazon Website and the REST API Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html), web site endpoints have no support for SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Turns this is possible and found out the way one should construct their URLs is like:

```
https://BUCKET-NAME.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/some/path/for/file.png
```

or another working option is (_if say your bucket has dots in the name)):

```
https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/BUCKET-NAME/some/path/for/file.png
```

*Of course change your region to match*